# Mysql between reverse range

Tags: mysql, between

Hi I am comparing two dates using mysql `between` function. My query looks like

```
select count(id) as total 
  from table 
 where user_id=111 
       and date_column BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
                           and NOW()
```

In between part of this query it is `BETWEEN upperdate and lowerdate`. It is working fine. But I went to verify this function on mysql documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between . It says it should be

```
`BETWEEN LOWER AND UPPER`
```

Current I am doing in reverse and it is working fine but I just want to verify that is it rite and it will cause in problem in future and any hidden case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working. Because:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) -- a day less than now is yesterday
```

is LOWER THAN

```
NOW() -- it is now, means today with current time
```

So comparison would be like

```
between yes'day and today
```

which is valid

Answer (score 2):

```
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and NOW()
```

is in other words

```
BETWEEN yesterday AND today
```

So it is

```
BETWEEN lower AND upper
```

No wonder it's working :)